# When IDLE does implicit print?

Tags: python

I want to have same behaviour as IDLE, in my Delphi app (it uses Python4Delphi and has Py console).

- When I enter e.g. `f=func()` in IDLE, this command is executed as is.
- When I enter simple value like `2+3` or `math.sin(math.pi/2)`, IDLE implicitly calls `print(2+3)` or `print(math.sin(math.pi/2))`.

In which cases IDLE calls implicit `print(...)`? How this depends on command string I enter into IDLE prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDLE prints non-`None` return values. If the return of a function is assigned to an object, it doesn't print it since it "went somewhere" (and the assignment operation doesn't return anything on its own)

```
>>> f = func()
>>> func()
hello world
```

Other operations like your math examples return that result as well, so they are printed

```
>>> a = 2 + 3
>>> 2 + 3
5
>>> a
5
```

Comment: Is it correct?: if string contains single "=" (not "==") then I should call it as is, else I should call "print()" (to emulate IDLE)?

Comment: `f = 10` doesn't return anything. 10 was *assigned* to f, but the full statement didn't return anything